# displaying columns not defined

Tags: r

```
dat1a <- data.frame(a=1:8, b=9:16, c=17:24, d = 25:32, e = 33:40)
dat1<-data.frame(a=1:6, b = 7:12)
dat2<-dat1[, !colnames(dat1) %in% dat1a]
dat2
```

Want to display c,d,e columns only.

Comment: Not clear about your expected output. Are you looking for `dat1a[setdiff(names(dat1a), names(dat1))]` or `dat1a[!names(dat1a) %in% names(dat1)]`

Comment: Makes no sense;  there no way to get columns "c","d" or "e" when using "[" on `dat1`. They simply are not there.

Comment: too vague, re-explain or prepare to get downvoted by others